# printing static headers in every printpage in chrome browser in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

hi i am working on code to print the page in my vue  web application . so in that i need to print static header in every page , either using css or js.i have created a header div component and made its position as fixed , its getting printed in all page but the content of body is cutted off half.

i need to print a logo , current time stamp in the header section

i adding code structure

```
      <div class="header">
      <div class="logo"> </div>
      <div class="time stamp"> </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the table > thead as your template.
If page is overflow to the new one, chrome will repeat the thead section.